# Is there any difference between virtual destructor=default and one with empty body?

Tags: c++, c++11, destructor

A virtual destructor which does nothing is

```
virtual ~ClassName() {}
```

Since C++11 [we can alternatively say](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21499427/673852):

```
virtual ~ClassName() = default;
```

Is there any difference between these two?

Comment: @Rakete1111: Actually it is not a duplicate, since the other question is about default destructors being public, and this one is about why one would use = default instead of {} in the virtual destructor that is necessary in a base class with virtual member functions. I was wondering the same thing, namely if the compiler can maybe optimize things differently with = default, or if it is simply more idiomatic C++11. It is after all quite a few more characters to type.

Comment: @Masseman Yes sure, they are not totally equivalent. But they ask the same question, should I use `{}` or `= default;` for the destructor? It doesn't matter that the destructor is virtual, because that's not what the question is about.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main difference is that there are rules for defaulted functions that specify under which circumstances they are deleted (cf. ISO c++14(`N4296`) 8.4, 12.1, 12.4, 12.8)

> 8.4.2.5: Explicitly-defaulted functions and implicitly-declared functions are collectively called defaulted functions, and the
>   implementation shall provide implicit definitions for them (12.1 12.4,
>   12.8), which might mean defining them as deleted.

e.g.:

> 12.4.5: A defaulted destructor for a class X is defined as deleted if: 
>   (5.1) — X is a union-like class that has a variant member with a
>   non-trivial destructor, (5.2) — any potentially constructed subobject
>   has class type M (or array thereof) and M has a deleted destructor or
>   a destructor that is inaccessible from the defaulted destructor, (5.3)
>   — or, for a virtual destructor, lookup of the non-array deallocation
>   function results in an ambiguity or in a function that is deleted or
>   inaccessible from the defaulted destructor

In case your use falls into one of the deleted categories, using `default` will be equivalent to using `delete` whereas `{}` won't be.